# “Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level” issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, compilation, compiler-errors, scapy

I am trying to make a program that sniffing DNS packets and then puts the qname of the packets into the 'key' of a dictionary and the dst ip of the packet into the 'value' of the dictionary and for some reason i get this error in line 6

```html
from scapy.all import *

def query_ip_name(dns_packet):
 dns_dict = {}

6-  strname = dns_packet[DNSQR].qname
    ip_add = dns_packet[IP].dst

    dns_dic.update(dns_name : dns_ip_name)



def filter_dns(packet):
      return (DNS in packet and packet[DNS].opcode == 0 and packet[DNSQR].qtype == 1)

def main():
      print 'Starting to sniff!'
      packets = sniff(count=30, lfilter=filter_dns, prn = query_ip_name)

      print 'The sniffing was successfully ended.'

      print 'The dictionary is : '



    

main()
```

Comment: The indentation of line 6 doesn't correspond to the lines above it inside the function, nor to the indentation of code outside the function.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I can not find any other problems. if i remove the 
"strname =" so it works well

Answer (score 1):

The definition of dns_dict is indented farther than strname  You need to have them at the same indentation as I show below. I see that you have the line number included in that line in your code snippet. Make sure that it is not in your code.

```
def query_ip_name(dns_packet):

    dns_dict = {}

    strname = dns_packet[DNSQR].qname
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
what is the problem with this line now:
' dns_dict.update(strname : ip_add) '?

Comment: @Shmuel What error does it show? What editor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix tabs and spaces. The line `dns_dict = {}` is indented with a tab while the rest of the file is intended with spaces. Replace the tab with 4 spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much,
what is the problem with this line now:
' dns_dict.update(strname : ip_add) '?

Comment: @Shmuel are you calling a function with a `:`: separating arguments instead of a `,`? That could be a typo.